# Is there a way to set default value in Mongoose schema with Javascript variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have my CurrentUser Value in a JS Variable and i have to set it in my moongoose schema as default value!! Is it Possible to set default value with variable??

`This is how my schema looks like`

```
   const momentschema = new mongoose.Schema({
       username:{
         type:String,
         default: CurrentUser
       },
       date : String ,
       time : String,
       place:String,
       color:String,
       saw:String,
       response:String, 
       },{
       timestamps: true 
       })
```

Comment: Hello Hariii, Thank you for your question, Yes, you can set a default value to a field for example `date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },` but setting a default value to a username may not be ideal, since `username` must a unique value. I would recommend setting up your schema and then writing a query to add a document using your `CurrentUser` value to your database. Hope that helps!